# What type of ultrasonic transducer would be suitable for ultrasonic welding?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, friction, welding, vibration, plastic

**Project background:**
I am working on a project where i need to weld plastic using ultrasonic transducers.

**Problem:**
Since I'm still learning engineering, I have a hard time figuring out what all the factors are in order to choose the right transducer.

**What I've done so far:**
I have searched the internet to find information regarding this subject, but due to (what seems to me) the wide area of knowledge needed, I haven't found anything that I properly can comprehend.

**Question:**

**Basically:** What do I need to take into account when choosing a transducer?

**Not-so-basically:**
I suspect that the properties of the material certainly affects the welding process, so here comes a sidequestion: what properties of the material do I need to know in order to calculate/decide which transducer to use?

Comment: Welcome to engineering SE. Can you please add all the research work you have done so far. This will help the community to provide you with a good answer.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena thank you. What exactly do you mean by adding? could you elaborate? I am a little bit confused now.

Comment: High quality question will result in a high quality response. Here is a link to guide you. http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. and this link http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264/how-can-a-new-user-ask-a-good-question-on-engineering-se/265#265... High quality question will attract your the attention, thus will result in high quality response. Example Question with 3K view: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/why-is-kva-not-the-same-as-kw

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena not really actually, except of a couple of other unanswered questions and some wikipedia articles. Thank you again. I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: I'm downvoting because I think that you should ask an ultrasonic welder vendor, not Engineering SE. If you discuss your exact application (dimensions, materials, etc) with a vendor, they would be *delighted* to recommend something to you.  Don't make the mistake of thinking that because you are a student you cannot call up companies and ask them for engineering advice about their products.

Comment: @regdoug yes, that sounds like a very good idea, if I'd wan't to risk letting someone steal my idea.

Comment: @Vaid: Your idea is already public, but here is something that I came across http://hackaday.com/2012/01/20/diy-ultrasonic-plastic-welding/

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena but that's not my idea. It's not a matter of plastic welding itself, it's about how I utilize it. That's the difference. I'm not trying to develop plastic ultrasonic welding itself, I'm developing something that utilizes it. And BTW, I've seen that article. It's a nice article.

Comment: @vaid if you don't want someone stealing your idea, you should probably file a provisional patent and ask the vendor to keep your idea confidential. That's what I have been taught to do. (Disclaimer: [IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL))

Comment: Also, I think Mahendra was trying to point you in the direction of figuring out how to build a ultrasonic plastic welder